# How to make one category in wordpress open only for autorized users

Tags: php, html, wordpress, frontend, backend

I have a site on Wordpress. There are three categories with records: A, B, C. I need to make A and B free to enter (like now) and C only for autorized users. Also, my php version is old and I can't use some plugins for that. I tried to solve it and I'm confused. Can you explain me how I can resolve it, please?

Comment: I am asking not for a code, but for an algorithm of writing it. Sorry if you understood me wrong, my English is not really good

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have various way to bound your category
you can add a php file in theme root folder like this category-c.php

```html
 <?php if (!defined('ABSPATH')) die('Direct access forbidden.');

if( is_user_logged_in() !== true ) {
    // write your code here 
}
else {
   // your code for logged out user 
}
```

Also you can check user role by using the code

```html
 if( is_user_logged_in() !== true ) {
  $user = wp_get_current_user();
  $allowed_roles = array( 'subscriber');
  if ( array_intersect( $allowed_roles, $user->roles ) || is_user_logged_in()) {
    // Your code here…
  }
} 
else {
  // your code for logged out user 
}
```